# Apache camel - How i can avoid coping same file in destination folder in single route

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to camel.

Requirement -

1. There are 4 files in folder.
2. Copy file1 to destination folder.
3. Wait for couple of minutes
4. Then copy file2,file3, file4 in destination folder.

Trying to do this in route as below,

```
        from("file://sourcePath?noop=true&include=.*.xml")
                .setHeader("myheader", simple("header"))
                .to("file://destPath")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                })
                .to("file://sourcePath?noop=true&include=.*.txt|.*.ts|.*.jpg")
                .to("file://destPath")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                })
```

Issues faced -

1. If i break it into 2 routes (from ()...to()-copy file1 and from ()...to()-copy file2,file3,file4) ,  i am not able to use header-> myheader in 2nd route.
2. If i try only one route (from ()...to()-copy file1,file2,file3,file4) , with same above code, it copies file1 in destination folder instead of file2,file3,file4

Comment: Any help here @Ramin Arabbagheri

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to try your first option, you can pass the Camel exchange to the second route by using the **direct:** Apache Camel component.

See below a working example:

```
from("file://sourcePath?noop=true&include=.*.xml")
                .setHeader("myheader", simple("header"))
                .to("file://destPath")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                })
                .to("direct:secondRoute");
from("direct:secondRoute")                
                .to("file://sourcePath?noop=true&include=.*.txt|.*.ts|.*.jpg")
                .to("file://destPath")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                })
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it behaves the same way as per issue2. :(

Answer (score 0):

Could you add FileFilter class?

```
public class MyFileFilter implements GenericFileFilter {
   public boolean accept(GenericFile pathname) {
      // we don't accept any files starting with skip in the name
      return !pathname.getFileName().startsWith("skip");
   }
}
```

.to("file://sourcePath?noop=true&filter=#myFileFilter")